# How to get the range for different sheets in an excel file to use to import in a macro?

Tags: sql, import, macros, sas

I am trying to import a few files which have multiple sheets. The variable names in each sheet start on different rows. My current code allows me to get all the sheet names in one dataset. I use that to store the sheet names in a macro list and then use a proc import within a do loop to import every sheet. The problem that I am facing is that the data on every sheet starts on a different line. I would like to know if there is a way to get the row number in every sheet at which the data starts so I can add in code to specify the particular ranges for every sheet in my import macro.

```
**********GETTING TAB NAMES****************

PROC SQL noprint;
    CONNECT TO pcfiles (path = "[ENTER FILE PATH HERE]");
    CREATE TABLE TABS_NAMES as
    SELECT * from connection to pcfiles (PCFILES::SQLColumns "","","","");                                                             
    DISCONNECT FROM pcfiles;
QUIT;

**********CLEANING TAB NAMES****************

Data Tab_names_1;
set TABS_NAMES;

    Clean_tab_name = dequote(tranwrd(TABLE_NAME,"$",""));
    if prxmatch ('/print/i',Table_name) > 0 then delete;
    keep TABLE_CAT  Clean_tab_name;

run;

Proc sort data = Tab_names_1 out = Tab_names_2 nodupkey;
    by _all_;
run;

**********STORING TAB NAMES**************** 

Proc sql noprint;
    select TABLE_CAT, Clean_tab_name
    into :Path1-:Path999, :Tab_Name1-:Tab_name999
    from Tab_names_2;
    %let max=&sqlobs.;
quit;

***************IMPORTING FILES*********

%MACRO  Import;
    %do i=1 %to &max.;
        Proc import
            datafile = "&&Path&i.."
            out      = Raw_Data_&i..
            dbms     = excelcs
            replace;
            sheet    = "&&Tab_Name&i..";
        run;    
    %end;
%mend;

%Import;
```

Comment: Unfortunately none that I know of. Excel isn't a great method of storing data, but that's usually beyond the programmers control in my experience. You can specify the range to import the data though, see the SAS documentation for the exact reference using the RANGE option.

Comment: Also, have you tried the libname method instead of PROC IMPORT? Assign a libname to your file and import all sheets at once using PROC COPY?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general (untested) idea for getting the first row of each tab dynamically.
Explanations are in comment in the code. This is a rough idea and will most likely require tinkering. Note for instance that I made the assumption that your tab names resolve to valid SAS table names

```
/* assign a libname using the appropriate excel engine (XLS or XLSX)*/
LIBNAME lib XLS "path-to-xls";

/* get the the list of sheets and variables in your excel and output it to 'contents' */
proc contents data=lib._all_ out=contents;
run;

/* get the list of tab names from the contents table and store them in macro variables */
proc sql noprint;
select distinct memname
into :tab1-
from contents
;
quit;


%macro import();
  %let i=1;
  /* iterate accross all your tabs */
  %do %while(%symexist(tab&i.));
    proc sql noprint;
      /* get the column names for the current tab in a comma separated list */
      select name
      into cols separated by ','
      from contents
      where name="&&tab&i."
      ;
      /* store the number of columns for the current tab in another macro variable */
      select count(name)
      into ncols
      from contents
      where name="&&tab&i."
      ;
    quit;
    /* go through each record of your tab until you encounter the first non-empty one and store the record number in a macro variable */
    data _null_;
      retain first 1;
      set lib.&&tab&i.;
      if cmiss(&cols.) = &ncols. then do;
        first=first+1;
        call symput("&&tab&i.",first);
      end;
      else stop;
    run;
    /* you now have the first record of each tab in a macro variable named after the corresponding tab */
    %put &&&&&&tab&i.;

    /* add some code to import your worksheet */

    %let i=%eval(&i+1);
  %end;
  %let n=%eval(&i-1);
%mend;
%import;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while back. I needed to import data from a specific sheet that contained a number of blank lines, as well as a useless header in the first column. The easiest solution I could come up with was to call a VB script from SAS (using SYSTASK) to export a clean sheet to a temporary csv file, which I could then import easily.

Here is the code for the script:

```
' deleteEmptyRows.vbs
'
' Script used to delete the first few rows in an Excel sheet prior to
' importing using a PROC IMPORT or an EXCEL LIBREF.
'
' Ex.: deleteEmptyRows <source.xls/xlsx> <sheet> <output.csv>

' Get the full paths.
Set tmpFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sourceFile = tmpFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
sheetName = Wscript.Arguments.Item(1)
outputFile = tmpFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(WScript.Arguments.Item(2))

Dim tmpExcel
Set tmpExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim tmpBook
Set tmpBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(sourceFile)

Dim tmpSheet
Set tmpSheet = oBook.Worksheets(sheetName)

' Delete rows until we reach an unempty one. We use the 2nd column
' to get around the header.
while (tmpSheet.cells(1, 2).value = "")
    tmpSheet.rows(1).delete
wend

' Save as CSV, and use local formats
tmpBook.SaveAs outputFile, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1

tmpBook.Saved = True
tmpExcel.Quit
```

In my case, I only had the one file to deal with, so I'm sure this can be streamlined in your case, but it should offer a starting point for what you need.